# Facebook Native App Login in iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios9

All!

I integrated FacebookiOS SDK 4.8 & also get up for iOS 9 as per describe on Facebook developer website.

But it always open web view in my native app automatically & ask for Login.

In 4.7 SDK, when I configure `LSApplicationQueryScheme` for iOS 9 then it works fine But now it does not.

**I want to get native Facebook App login**

Help me for this!

**Thanks**

Comment: Did you added the Uri schemes

Comment: @bmindhackers, yes I added URI Scheme

Comment: @user2526811 You got any solution for this question ?

Comment: @JayBhalani, Still NO :)
are you also facing the same issue?

Comment: Yes, i have same issue. are you get solution please tell me  @user2526811

Comment: @JayBhalani, Still I am not get any solution for this. We will let you know each other if find any solution